# Running/debugging simple website with JavaScript in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

In the past, I've written several ASP.NET Core apps that have some JavaScript in them.  When I start my app for testing within Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2022 if that matters ... not Visual Studio Code) I can easily debug directly in VS.  I simply click F5, the ASP.NET app launches, then the browser opens up (I'm using Edge if it matters), and my javascript breakpoints are caught in VS.  I'm a happy guy.

So now, I want to edit/debug a simple non-ASP based website with some JavaScript files in Visual Studio.  When I open this website as "a local folder" in VS, I can edit things just fine, but I don't have the ability to press F5 to start the site and run the debugger.  I don't see a way to set a "Startup item" in this case and I can't debug my scripts.

Is there a better way to open a simple website project like this (or a better way to configure things) that will let me use the same debugging as I had in my ASP.NET Core projects?

Comment: This may or may not help, but the devtools in most browsers allow you to set and hit breakpoints too. Just in case there's no way to do exactly what you want, you can at least use that..